# How to modify current driver files in USB_Host_Shield2.0 on github for Arduino Mega ADK USB driver for Epson LQ-310 printer?

Tags: arduino-mega, usb

At the moment, I am engaged in a project in which I have to drive Epson LQ-310 printer with Arduino Mega ADK (USB Host). There is already a library  USB_Host_Shield_2.0 on Github which includes usb drivers for keyboard, flash drive etc. but not for a printer.

I am thinking to modify the current header files (adk.h and adk.cpp) based on Android drivers to suit for a printer. Do the things workout in this way?

Could anyone of you please suggest me the things to modify to achieve the required functionality?

Thank You

Comment: start here https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/usbprint11a021811.pdf

Comment: and you will need this http://gimp-print.sourceforge.net/reference-html/c463.html#AEN474